# Media files end up in in a pycharm subdirectory when uploading

Tags: django, upload, directory, settings, media

I am building a Django application on a Windows system where the user should be able to upload images.
But somehow my uploades files end up in my Program Files directory at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.1\jre\jre\bin\WebApp\media\TestData\static\images
```

I just can't understand why I get this result. I would like to store these Images on another disk such as:

```
G:\General\Users\Me\WebApp\media
```

I have been trying to change my MEDIA_ROOT but without any success. Im not even sure if that's were the problem is or if I don't fully understand how uploading with Django works.

These are my settings:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('__file__')))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

Don't know if it matters but i am using a ModelForm from a model with an Imagefield.

Comment: User uploaded files go to the absolute path specified by `MEDIA_ROOT`, which should be able to point anywhere you have write permissions. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root

Comment: I think your `BASE_DIR` should be `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Comment: Thanks @xyres! It looks like it solved it :)
Stupid small errors

Comment: @Eitre Hi. Glad it helped. I posted my comment as answer. If you could *accept* it, it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BASE_DIR` should look like:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```